# How to Use HTTPS with DHCP in ownCloud?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, ssl, raspberrypi

System: Ubuntu 14.04 server, Apache 2.4, ownCloud 8.2.5, testing environment Raspbian Jessie on Raspberry Pi 3 b. Error in Server's Internet Browser about HTTPS, when accessing `https://192.168.1.107` and `https://192.168.1.107`

```
Error performing TLS handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Debugging

- Command `telnet 192.168.1.107 80` just hangs there for HTTP, similarly as `telnet 192.168.1.107 443` for HTTPS.
- Accessing HTTP works when acccessing `http://192.168.1.107` and `http://192.168.1.107/owncloud` in the internet browser, but not by `telnet` as before
- Logs `/var/log/apache2/error.log` has no recent errors. No errors in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and not `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`.

The output of `sudo apache2ctl -M |sort` is

```
access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 core_module (static)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http_module (static)
Loaded Modules:
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 so_module (static)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 unixd_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
```

My settings should be the about the same as John's

1. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`: `000-default.conf` and `000-default-ssl.conf`.
2. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`: `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-ssl.conf`.
3. `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`: `owncloud.conf`
4. `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`: `ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/owncloud.conf` and other symlinks.
5. `error-ssl.log` and `access-ssl.log` used not to mix them with standard logs in `sites-available/000-default-ssl.conf`.

My `ssl` certificates and keys are in `/etc/ssl/`. 
My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` where I followed the thread [here](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=2751)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache.key
```

where my only difference is that I do not have these lines `SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/subca.crt; SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/ca.crt` because I should not have a ChainFile. 
File `/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php` is

```
<?php 
$CONFIG = array ( 
'instanceid' => 'yours', 
'passwordsalt' => 'yours', 
'secret' => 'yours', 
'trusted_domains' => 
array ( 
0 => '192.168.1.107', 
1 => '192.168.1.1', 
2 => 'localhost', 
), 
'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data', 
'overwrite.cli.url' => '192.168.1.107/owncloud', 
'dbtype' => 'sqlite3', 
'version' => '8.2.5.2', 
'logtimezone' => 'UTC', 
'installed' => true, 
'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu', 
'theme' => '', 
'loglevel' => 2, 
'maintenance' => false, 
'trashbin_retention_obligation' => 'auto', 
'mail_from_address' => 'masimasi', 
'mail_smtpmode' => 'sendmail', 
'mail_domain' => 'gmail.com', 
'mail_smtpauthtype' => 'LOGIN', 
'mail_smtphost' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
'mail_smtpport' => '587', 
);
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-ssl.conf` is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c> 
<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
ServerName localhost 

DocumentRoot /var/www/html 

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log 
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined 

SSLEngine on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIU

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache.key 

SetEnvIf User-Agent .*MSIE.* nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown 
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log \ 
   "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b" 

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$"> 
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars 
</FilesMatch> 
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin> 
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 
</IfModule>
```

Permissions/owners `644/root:root` should be right about SSL

```
ls -ls /etc/apache2/ssl/ 
total 8 
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1484 May 31 15:17 apache.crt 
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1704 May 31 15:17 apache.key
```

Settings in `sites-x` where two symlinks

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available/ 
total 16 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 21:52 . 
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 31 15:44 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 183 May 31 19:43 000-default.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 916 May 31 21:50 000-default-ssl.conf
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ 
total 8 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 19:38 . 
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 31 15:44 .. 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 May 31 19:35 000-default.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 May 31 11:50 000-default-ssl.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Settings in `conf-x` where 7 symlinks

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/conf-available/ 
total 40 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 20:07 . 
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 31 15:44 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 315 Oct 24 2015 charset.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127 Jul 29 2013 javascript-common.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3224 Oct 24 2015 localized-error-pages.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189 Oct 24 2015 other-vhosts-access-log.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 410 May 31 19:11 owncloud.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 655 Feb 19 2015 phppgadmin.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2190 Nov 28 2015 security.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 455 Oct 24 2015 serve-cgi-bin.conf
ls -la /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ 
total 8 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 13:45 . 
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 31 15:44 .. 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May 31 11:50 charset.conf -> ../conf-available/charset.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 May 31 11:50 localized-error-pages.conf -> ../conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 May 31 11:50 other-vhosts-access-log.conf -> ../conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 31 13:45 owncloud.conf -> ../conf-available/owncloud.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 May 31 12:03 phppgadmin.conf -> ../conf-available/phppgadmin.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 31 11:50 security.conf -> ../conf-available/security.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 May 31 11:50 serve-cgi-bin.conf -> ../conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

**JohnOrion's hypothesis about the problem**:

> you may try setting youself up on a static ip address and setting up the network properly so you can type localhost into the browser on the server machine and it should go to the site .. if it doesnt .. that could be an issue .. if the ssl is looking for localhost but it cant find it becuase for some reason your network doesnt show localhost pointig to your local ip .. that cold be a cause.

**My hypothesis about the problem**. Output of the command `curl --head localhost | grep Server` is `Server: Apache/2.4.10` where nothing said that SSL modules are correctly loaded. I think this should be done in some cases. Not sure.

### Making SSL key/crt

[Thread](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2418) about doing the .key and .crt.

> the problem isn't that it was an self signed cert, but the common name
>   have to include the subdomain. i only signed the cert with the common
>   name domain.com but my owncloud is running in cloud.domain.com

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288520/16920) however about localhost so *commonname* should only be `192.168.1.107` without a trailing slash, which is now correct in my system.

---

**How do you sign self-certificate for localhost?** 
I include `192.168.1.107/owncloud` in the commonname but not sure if it is right.

How can you use self-signed HTTPS with DHCP in ownCloud?

Comment: we need more information than ... url fails ... why does it fail? what errors do you see on the site .. what errors do you see in the /var/apache2/error.log? Not sure what you are showing in your redirect thing. that shouldn't be in the config.php. Is the server working...can you get to localhost itself?

Comment: ahh ok so it works but the redirect isnt working properly .. I get it now. Are you sure that redirect is enabled in apache? `sudo apache2ctl -M | sort` and look under loaded modules to make sure that rewrite_module is showing there.

Comment: actually with Redirect permanent I guess the rewrite module doesn't matter I use rewrite rules for mine

Comment: ok .. looking though it I noticed one thing .. on your redirect it should read `Redirect permanent / https://localhost/` it may be that you didn't have the trailing `/` at the end so it was trying to access `https://localhostownecloud`

Comment: I think your server is set up wrong. Is what you printed above the full contents of your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` .. if you want we can set up a chat and it may be easier to do troubleshooting

Comment: You might try the configuration script mail-in-abox https://mailinabox.email/ which owncloud over https ( as well as email)

Comment: ok your error log is located where every your default apache log directory is located .. I would change that to /var/log/apache2/error.log ... you may have to create the directory first though. Restart the server.. then you will be able to see your error log .. I don't know what the default one is set too.. never seen it set up that way by default. and the other answer with adding the ssl site also is needed .. didn't realize that wasnt done yet

Comment: just change it in that default file .. change it from `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` to `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log` then run `sudo service apache2 restart` you can do the same for the access log changing it to `CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably failing because you have not configured the server for https. Apache configuration for https requires that you listen to port 443 as well as port 80 and configure the server for TLS with a certificate.

(example from apache documentation)

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

[Ubuntu documentation for configuring HTTPS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration)

Comment: Should I put this one to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`? I am newbie about the topic so I do not know the best practices.

Comment: no this should be a sperate one .. should be 000-default-ssl.conf

Comment: you want to edit conf files in etc/apache2/sites-available  the sites-enabled directory should be links to the conf files in sites-available

Comment: that is incorrect the owncloud.conf is not a site it is a conf. it should be in the conf-available  and symlinked to conf-enabled folder. The owncloud install should have done this already so if you have a link to the onwncloud in sites enabled then remove it. it does not need to be there

Comment: basically in sites-enabled you should only have two files that are symlinked to the sites-available folder .. they should be 000-default.conf and 000-default-ssl.conf. as i satated above the owncloud confs are dealt with in the conf-available/conf-enabled folders

Comment: I think there are too many cooks in the kitchen. We seem to be getting confused. I think you are adding stuff to the wrong files. you mentioned the IfModule and LoadModule in the same question but they are to be put in two different files so .. i think we are doing more damage than helping at this point in time.. I'm surprised that the comments have been able to go on for this long without it trying to put us in a chat room .. I wish it would because it would be a lot easier to try to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40553/discussion-between-john-orion-and-masi).

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to not have a full website enabled and maybe that's why you can't get the redirect to work. I have tried to recreate this issue .. the first problem I found was the redirect was not adding the `/` which I mentioned. Since that didn't solve the issue I also used the rewrite function to force owncloud to go to https. This is how I managed that:

Go to the directory owncloud is located `/var/www/owncloud` and open the .htaccess file.

Scroll down to near the bottom where you will see `#### DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE ####` right under that add the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

so it should look something like this

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>
#### DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE ####
#### Part you need to add #####
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>
#### end of part you need to add ####
ErrorDocument 403 /owncloud/core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /owncloud/core/templates/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule . index.php [PT,E=PAT
```

That should use the rewrite rule to force owncloud to run under https

Comment: all you are adding is the first section i put in .. the second shows it added in the file i have already .. yours may have different things in there but you should have the line that says DO NOT CHANGE .. you just need to add the 4 lines i posted right under that line without effecting any of the other lines in the file

Comment: basically you have it working but your configuration is all messed up and not set up properly. There is a chat room set up now if you would like to join and I could make sure everything is set up properly .. but if its working and you aren't dealing with an actual server but just trying to use owncloud then you are ok the way it is ... but if you wanted to run a website or something else then you will have issues most likely because of the poor configuration

Comment: I took a new approach to solve the case by considering only HTTPS with Apache2. Too complex with ownCloud too. Thread here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291482/16920 where using the guide about setting HTTPS in apache (first link there).