# What are Risks of Not Using HTTPS in local network of ownCloud in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi, https, owncloud-server

I cannot setup HTTPS with self-signed certificate in ownCloud of Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, where testing on Raspberry Pi 3b, as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/779965/25388) about *How to Use HTTPS with DHCP in ownCloud?*

---

What are the risks of using HTTP in local network of ownCloud in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how much you trust your local network.  Http isn't inherently dangerous, however the data leak could be.  If you have a small network where you manage the machines and services it could be trusted, no problem.

If you could use ssl, you should, but if you can't like in your scenario, I wouldn't hesitate to use owncloud with http for local clients.

The other consideration is the sensitivity of the data on owncloud.  If it's music, pictures, typical storage data, it would seem like less risk.  If you're storing and transferring tax documents, trade secrets, nsa files, you should use https.

Keep in mind, https only encrypts the data while in transit, the files on your client and server are not encrypted while being stored unless you set that up seperately.

Comment: I have a router and my PCs in the network. Router has a firewall. Only ethernet connection and Wifi G/N from the router to PCs. The only weakness can be with the internet connection provider. This is a student housing and I do not know if they have linked the connections together in a chain such that other students could read other messages. I do not see any other PCs in the network. How can you see if the source of internet is safe? - I do not know other ways how the attacker could get to my network.

Comment: Having your router where it is will secure your network to a reasonable level.  Everyone on the network may be able to see your router, but maybe not, and even if they can, there's no harm in that.  There meant to be internet facing devices.  As long as your wifi is encrypted (aes/tkip). You're good to go, imho.

Comment: What about ethernet protection? How can you the source of the internet i.e. ISP be vulnerable to other attacks?

Comment: in your case, if your router was running on an old firmware that could be compromised, that would be your concern.  When you start routing external traffic to internal services then you open up more possibilities but if your router doesn't pass traffic to your lan then there is a reason sense of security.  There are no certainties in security, just a sense of safety.  I put a deadbolt on my house but someone still can kick down the door, I know that, but at least it is locked.

Comment: I am using TP-link 300 Mb (actually 450 Mb) router with default settings and the newest stable firmware, having daily rebooting times, so it should be rather safe.

Comment: @masi : What was the problem while setting up HTTPS.  If you want to discuss , welcome to chat : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41182/owncloud-https